# Partial cover the screen and slide the overlay-element

Tags: jquery, css

I try to create an overlay-div, which covers the whole screen - except 3em to the bottom. I think my attempt is not the optimum:

```
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#background {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    top: -3em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

With that, I want to slide up and down the overlay. But with the css above, I don't know how to animate completely as '-55em' are too much on lower screen resolution or not enough on higher resolution:

**JS:**

```
$('#overlay').animate({'top':'-55em'}, 1000, function() {
    $('#overlay').animate({'top':'-3em'}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Something like this? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbgopon2/)

Comment: @Tambo Modifying OP's post with a specific jquery version could change the context of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should change height instead of top it will save you from typical calculations

```js
$('#overlay').animate({'height':'0%'}, 1000, function() {
 $('#overlay').animate({'height':'100%'}, 1000);
});
```

```css
 #background {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }

 #overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  top: -3em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background"></div>
 <div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But with my CSS there are 3em overlapping on the top margin. As I do the animation it will go to the real top of the overlay, that means 3em more than the margin goes. Know what I mean?

Comment: its simple just change height:0% to height:3em or if i am not getting what you exactly want please tell me