# Positioning and centering of an scalable

Tags: css

1) I tried to show a image (wrapped by a container) vertical centred and centered in the left half of a container. (Based on my last post: [Partial cover the screen and slide the overlay-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396673/partial-cover-the-screen-and-slide-the-overlay-element))

2) The problem is, that the image is a svg-file and it should fit to the user screen, so it has a dynamic width and height. I'm using 47% width and the height should be set automatic as to keep the ratio.

For the first part (centering and positioning) this is the fiddle, which is working: http://jsfiddle.net/gbgopon2/10/

As you can see the red placeholder has a given height and width.

Now I tried to add the image and change the width without a height. And that doesn't work at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/gbgopon2/13/

So maybe someone has a better solution to put a scalable svg-image with dynamic dimensions on the page in that way that it is centered vertical and centered in the left half of the screen...
And why doesn't the image disapear while sliding the overlay-container?

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#background {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
#overlay {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0em;
    right: 0em;
    top: -3em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 1;
}
#position {
    width: 40%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    left: 25%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="position">
        <img src="http://placeskull.com/170/170">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of [ghost element](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) was tested with IE11, Firefox and Chrome:

```
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    #background {
        background-color: #ddd;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        position: absolute; z-index: 0;
    }
    #overlay {
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute; left: 0em; right: 0em; top: -3em;
        background-color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden; /* it hides the image it's covered */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #position {
        position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 50%; /* EDIT: added to center in the left half of the screen */
        text-align: center; height: 100%;
    }
    #position:before {
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #position img {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gzc6nbvv/9/

[image: result]

> why doesn't the image disapear while sliding the overlay-container?

Adding `overflow: hidden;` in the `#overlay` selector solves it.

Comment: This seems to work. You centered the image horizontal and vertical. But I need to center it horizontal in the left half of the screen (vertical center is correct). How do I do that? Edit: I did it like this: text-align: left; margin-left: 10%; for #position. Is that a correct way?

Comment: I added **width: 50%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;** inside the  **#position** selector: http://jsfiddle.net/gzc6nbvv/9/embedded/result/ . Is this what you'd like?

Answer (score 0):

Using only css is very difficult to set exactly at the center if you dont`n know the image ratio... You have to use percentage to position it...
(sorry for my terrible english)

try something like this (this probably is not your final solution, but you can extract something util here) :

```
#position img{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -49.7%;
    margin-top: -37%;
}
```

Comment: My problem is, that I do not know the size of the image as it should be displayed dynamically (bigger screen = bigger image)

Comment: So this would be the code: http://jsfiddle.net/gbgopon2/14/ Looks better, but there are a still some mistakes. Why doesn't the image slide in?

Comment: It's because we are using the width as referece... Lets use height as reference...

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: This seems to only work Chrome

The trick is to use `display: table`:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#background {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    position: absolute; z-index: 0;
}
#overlay {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute; left: 0em; right: 0em; top: -3em;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 1; overflow: hidden;
}
#position {
    background: red;
    position: absolute; left: 25%; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 40%; 
    display: table; text-align: center; margin: auto;
}
#position img {
    display: block; margin: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gzc6nbvv/1/

Comment: Unfortunatly the image doesnt slide in :-(

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/gzc6nbvv/6/embedded/result/ I added an "overflow: hidden".

Comment: It seems the image centering and sliding animation are behaving very differently between browsers.

Comment: Apparently it only works with Chrome (sorry!). I posted another answer that was tested with three browsers.